# MacOSX Big Sur - Terminal ZSH Shell Command's Execute Sometimes With "!" Exclamation Symbol In Front

Tags: terminal, mac, big-sur, zsh

Is this normal behavior for MacOS Big Sur ZSH (Z Shell) terminal?   Sometimes shell commands such as `find` and or `launchd` as just a simple example execute properly. This is with the exclamation symbol **"!"** in front, leading with the expected output and no privilege escalation.

For example, running: `!find /` will still work.
Or `!sudo` will execute.

But `!echo '@'` will not. But lead to the next command sometimes.

> Output for **!echo**

`zsh: event not found: echo`

> Output for **!launchd**

`launchd`

`launchd cannot be run directly.`

It seem's weird `!sudo` outputs `sudo syscallbypid.d`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

!str   Refer to the most recent command starting with str.
this is the history expansion behavior.
type

```
man zshexpn
```

and check 'Event Designators', you will get the answer

> An event designator is a reference to a command-line entry in the history list.  In the list below, remember that the initial `!'  in
> each item may be changed to another character by setting the histchars parameter.

```
   !      Start a history expansion, except when followed by a blank, newline, `=' or `('.  If followed immediately by a word designator
          (see the section `Word Designators'), this forms a history reference with no event designator (see the section `Overview').

   !!     Refer to the previous command.  By itself, this expansion repeats the previous command.

   !n     Refer to command-line n.

   !-n    Refer to the current command-line minus n.

   !str   Refer to the most recent command starting with str.

   !?str[?]
          Refer to the most recent command containing str.  The trailing `?' is necessary if this reference is to be followed by a modi-
          fier or followed by any text that is not to be considered part of str.

   !#     Refer  to  the  current command line typed in so far.  The line is treated as if it were complete up to and including the word
          before the one with the `!#' reference.

   !{...} Insulate a history reference from adjacent characters (if necessary).
```

Comment: Possibly of note, while ZSH has a handful of quirks, most of this is in fact not unique to ZSH, and works largely similarly in most other modern shells that provide history expansion.

Comment: @nelson Thanks for the great answer really informative and appreciated. Also, Austin thanks for that info as well.